# StAX Parser Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, xml, stax

It's my hometask. I don't understand what it want from me and why it doesn't work. It fails on the reader.next() . The path is right. Here's the code on Java of StAXParser:

```
public class StAXParser {

private Dances dances;
private Dance currentDance;
private Dancer currentDancer;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StAXParser stAXParser = new StAXParser();
    stAXParser.parse("DanceGroupConcerts.xml");
}

public Dances getDances() {
    return dances;
}

public StAXParser() {
}

public void parse (String xmlFileName){
    try {
        XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(xmlFileName));
        int tag;
        String tagName;
        String text = new String();
        while (reader.hasNext()){
            tag = reader.next();

            switch (tag){
                case XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT:

                    tagName = reader.getLocalName();

                    if (tagName == "Dances")
                        dances = new Dances();
                    if (tagName.equals("Dance"))
                        currentDance = new Dance();
                    if (tagName.equals("Dancer"))
                        currentDancer = new Dancer();
                    break;

                case XMLStreamReader.CHARACTERS:
                    text = reader.getText();
                    break;

                case XMLStreamReader.END_ELEMENT:

                    tagName = reader.getLocalName();

                    if (tagName.equals("Dancer"))
                        currentDance.getDancers().add(currentDancer);
                    if (tagName.equals("Dance"))
                        dances.getDance().add(currentDance);
                    if (tagName.equals("Type"))
                        currentDance.setType(text);
                    if (tagName.equals("Scene"))
                        currentDance.setScene(text);
                    if (tagName.equals("NumberOfDancers"))
                        currentDance.setNumberOfDancers(NumberOfDancers.fromValue(text));
                    if (tagName.equals("Music"))
                        currentDance.setMusic(Music.fromValue(text));
                    if (tagName.equals("Name"))
                        currentDancer.setName(text);
                    if (tagName.equals("DanceTeam"))
                        currentDancer.setNameOfDanceTeam(text);
                    if (tagName.equals("Age"))
                        currentDancer.setAge(BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(text)));
                    if (tagName.equals("Experience"))
                        currentDancer.setExperience(BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(text)));
                    if (tagName.equals("Number"))
                        currentDance.setNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(text)));

                    break;
            }


        }

    } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

And XSD:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:Dance="Dancers"
targetNamespace="Dancers">
  <simpleType name="Type">
    <restriction base="string"></restriction>
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="Scene">
    <restriction base="string"></restriction>
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="NumberOfDancers">
    <restriction base="string">
      <enumeration value="mass"></enumeration>
      <enumeration value="solo"></enumeration>
      <enumeration value="pair"></enumeration>
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="Music">
    <restriction base="string">
      <enumeration value="phonogram"></enumeration>
      <enumeration value="alive"></enumeration>
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="Number">
    <restriction base="integer"></restriction>
  </simpleType>

    <simpleType name="Name">
    <restriction base="string"></restriction>
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="DanceTeam">
    <restriction base="string"></restriction>
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="Age">
    <restriction base="integer"></restriction>
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="Experience">
    <restriction base="integer"></restriction>
  </simpleType>


  <complexType name="Dancer">
    <sequence>
      <choice>
        <element name="name" type="Dance:Name"></element>
        <element name="nameOfDanceTeam" type="Dance:DanceTeam"></element>
      </choice>
      <element name="age" type="Dance:Age"></element>
      <element name="experience" type="Dance:Experience"></element>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

    <complexType name = "Dance">
     <sequence>
       <element name="type" type="Dance:Type"></element>
       <element name="scene" type="Dance:Scene"></element>
       <element name="numberOfDancers" type="Dance:NumberOfDancers"></element>
       <element name="music" type="Dance:Music"></element>
       <element name="dancers" type="Dance:Dancer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"></element>
       <element name="number" type="Dance:Number"></element>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>


  <element name="Dances">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="Dance" type="Dance:Dance" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>
</schema>
```

And XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Dances>
<Dance>
    <Type>Folk</Type>

    <Scene>Dr. Frank N. Furter Major</Scene>

    <NumberOfDancers>mass</NumberOfDancers>

    <Music>phonogram</Music>

    <Dancer>
        <Name>Majenta</Name>
        <Age>25</Age>
        <Experience>25</Experience>
    </Dancer>

    <Dancer>
        <Name>Riff Raff</Name>
        <Age>2500</Age>
        <Experience>25</Experience>
    </Dancer>

    <Dancer>
        <Name>Columbia</Name>
        <Age>25</Age>
        <Experience>25</Experience>
    </Dancer>

    <Dancer>
        <DanceTeam>Guests</DanceTeam>
        <Age>2566</Age>
        <Experience>667</Experience>
    </Dancer>

    <Number>1</Number>
</Dance>
</Dances>
```

Thank's for help. Sorry if my english was too bad.

Comment: SAX Parser works well. I can't see strange characters in XML- and XSD- file in Notepad++. Does it show them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with your XML-File. There is some (invisible) content before the `<?xml...` which causes the parser to fail.
See this question for a possible solution: [Content is not allowed in Prolog SAXParserException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569123/content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-saxparserexception)

To answer your edit: It is possible that you won't see this as a visible character in Notepad++ - check the following url for a possible solution: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-handle-utf8-file-with-bom.html

Comment: Alternatively, in the XSD (which I assume is being parsed as well). Since the pasted file shows spaces before `<?xml`, I'd put my money there.

Comment: OK, i add this to the code:

`BOMInputStream bomIN = new BOMInputStream(new` `FileInputStream(xmlFileName));`
            `if (bomIN.hasBOM() == false){`

And it seems, it hasn't strange symbols inside.

Comment: Oh. Now it pass. Thank you!