# UTF-16LE encoding and xerces2 Java

Tags: java, xml, utf-16, xerces, byte-order-mark

I went through a few posts, like [FileReader reads the file as a character stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18659546/1549977) and [can be treated as whitespace if the document is handed as a stream of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7697281/1549977) where the answers say the input source is actually a char stream, not a byte stream.

However, the suggested solution from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18659546/1549977) does not seem to apply to UTF-16LE. Although I use this code:

```java
    try (final InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(filename.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.READ)) {
      DOMParser parser = new org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser();
      parser.parse(new InputSource(is));
      return parser.getDocument();
    } catch (final SAXParseException saxEx) {
      LOG.debug("Unable to open [{}}] as InputSource.", absolutePath, saxEx);
    }
```

I still get `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.`.

I looked at Files.newInputStream, and it indeed uses a `ChannelInputStream` which will hand over bytes, not chars. I also tried to set the Encoding of the InputSource object, but with no luck.
I also checked that  there are not extra chars (except the BOM) before the `<?xml` part.

I also want to mention that this code works just fine with UTF-8.

// Edit: 
I also tried DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse() and XmlInputStreamReader.next(), same results.

// Edit 2: 
Tried using a buffered reader. Same results:
Unexpected character '뿯' (code 49135 / 0xbfef) in prolog; expected '<'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you remove the BOM at the beginning (skipping the first two bytes)? `... { is.read(): is.read();`

Comment: Then I wouldn't be able to read UTF-8 without bom or ISO-8859-1. :(

Comment: The encoding is given or defaulted UTF-8 in `<?xml encoding=...?>`. I have heard that in rare cases a BOM gave such a problem. But I do not remember specifics.

Comment: I cannot get even this far. I want to read that tag and attribute you refer to. But see my 2nd edit, it stops before that.

Comment: I double checked. The file is starting with the BOM 0xFF 0xFE. Maybe I need to wrap it into a BOMRemovingInputStream…

Comment: Shouldn't you set the character encoding on the input source before parsing (`inputSource.setEncoding("UTF-16");`) so it uses the BOM to determine whether it's LE or BE?

Comment: Yes and no. The XML libraries are mature enough to do this right now. The correct answer was "maven resource filtering". Since maven is set to UTF-8, my tests failed reading from the target/classes folder, but my input (from the src/test/resources-folder) was okay.

Answer (score 1):

To get a bit farther some info gathering:

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(filename.toPath);
String xml = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
if (xml.startsWith("\uFEFF")) {
    LOG.info("Has BOM and is evidently UTF_16LE");
    xml = xml.substring(1);
}
if (!xml.contains("<?xml")) {
    LOG.info("Has no XML declaration");
}
String declaredEncoding = xml.replaceFirst("<?xml[^>]*encoding=[\"']([^\"']+)[\"']", "$1");
if (declaredEncoding == xml) {
    declaredEncoding = "UTF-8";
}
LOG.info("Declared as " + declaredEncoding);

try (final InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(declaredEncoding))) {
  DOMParser parser = new org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser();
  parser.parse(new InputSource(is));
  return parser.getDocument();
} catch (final SAXParseException saxEx) {
  LOG.debug("Unable to open [{}}] as InputSource.", absolutePath, saxEx);
}
```

Comment: I looked into the file with `xxd` and I know it is \uFFFE at the beginning.

Comment: bytes FF FE are in UTF-16LE actually the char `\uFEFF` aka the BOM ( a bit weird Unicode number)

Comment: Hey, an aside. As the BOM in UTF-8 bytes is `EF BB BF`  that would explain your edit-2:  0xbfef somewhat.

Comment: both IntelliJ  and `file` show  this is a UTF-16LE file. UTF16LE starts with `\uFFFE`. `\uFFFE` is not weired, according to Wikipedia it is the "no character" character. The 2nd edit used UTF-8 interpretation by accident, no change when I put back UTF16LE in again :(

Comment: Well I could always use https://github.com/gpakosz/UnicodeBOMInputStream

Comment: (Bytes FF FE is in UTF-16 little endian the number 0xfeff hence U+FEFF or in java `\uFEFF`.) The mere point I wanted to make: (1) the BOM sometimes seems to be problematic, maybe only for UTF-16LE. (2) The declared encoding must agree with the bytes for XML parsing.

Comment: (takes a deeeeeep breath) … MAVEN RESOURCE FILTERING. I was looking at the source all along, but when looking at the target you could see some extra bytes at the beginning o/t file. Very sorry to see this :(