# SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, tomcat, sax

I need to add the following file to my Tomcat's '/conf' directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context useHttpOnly="false" path="/bbc">
    <Realm className="com.bbc.tomcat.BBCSecurityRealm"/>
</Context>
```

After adding this file, I get the following error when Tomcat starts up"

```
ERROR ecmdefault util.digester.Digester 18:37:14,477 localhost-startStop-1 : Parse Fatal Error at line 1 column 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:388)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1427)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138696/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your xml file has some invisible chars (most likely the BOM) at the start (before `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`) which is not allowed in xml. you could view it using a hex editor. Simplest way to fix it is to create an empty text file and copy the content into it, change the extension to xml.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4570015/1113392) for further help.

From http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-handle-utf8-file-with-bom.html

> UTF8 file are a special case because it is not recommended to add a BOM to them because it can break other tools like Java. In fact, Java assumes the UTF8 don't have a BOM so if the BOM is present it won't be discarded and it will be seen as data.

Comment: Right! In my case just replacing the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but this reference [link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/sax-error-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog/) provided the solution spot on.

Quote from the article.

***Any characters before the start of the XML content will cause above error.***

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog error message.
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this error with a line that opened with another tag than it was closed with.

I also had a double entry of one line in the xml, and I cannot trace back which of the two mistakes threw this error, but I guess it was the wrong closing tag.