# How can I solve the lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I am trying to run my XSLT project. But I am getting the following error,

> lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

I tried this removing `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and comment that is just after `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` from each and every file. But It also shows the same error. How can I fix this? I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: Regarding your edit, why did you remove important information from your question, including that the error message originated from Saxon?

Comment: @kjhughes Actually I think my file content is not important here. If you ask me to add them again I can add them. I have validated my files and They all are well formated.

Comment: Your file content is certainly important, but the problem may very well reside in different files that you've not included -- be sure to check (mostly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19898942/290085) but perhaps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51500738/290085) as well) not only the XSLT, but the XML (and any XSDs) as well.  (And regardless you shouldn't have edited the error message unless you weren't in fact using Saxon.)

Answer (score 1):

First step is to find out which XML file is causing the trouble. Saxon would output the file name if it knew it; the fact that you aren't seeing a file name might mean that the input is an anonymous stream rather than a file. Look for cases where you create a Source object from a FileInputStream without supplying a system Id.

Getting a stack trace for the exception will help you to identify where in your code you need to look.

The message from Xerces typically comes when the first character of a file that's submitted for XML parsing isn't "<". But experience shows that this can be a symptom with a wide variety of root causes. Removing the XML declaration from a file is very unlikely to help (but removing a blank line before the XML declaration most definitely would).

Comment: Still no progress.

Comment: @user_v12: Check each of your XML/XSLT/XSD files against the possibilities listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19898942/290085) (and do not delete and repost your question again!).

Comment: Have you got a stack trace for the exception?

Comment: It's also possible that the error is not in any file, but in some in-memory XML that's generated and consumed within your application. You've told us so little about the application that we really can't rule anything like this out.