# Error importing WSDL : org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: azure, web-services, soapui

We are testing a simple SOAP based Web service, deployed in Azure. While accessing the WSDL from SoapUI client (5.7.0), we are getting this error:- `org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Content is not allowed in prolog.`

We are going through the various posts but yet to get a breakthrough. Any clue on what could be wrong?

The WSDL: https://testsoapws.azurewebsites.net/WebS1.asmx?WSDL

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Content is not allowed in prolog" error yet nothing before XML declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51500738/content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-error-yet-nothing-before-xml-declaration)

Comment: Thanks @DeepDave-MT. I went through the link. However I am not constructing a XML request programmatically. I am trying to import the WSDL in SoapUI client, and that is when I hit the error. I am able to browse through the WSDL in browser.