# "Error:Gradle: Content is not allowed in prolog" when running tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

Using Android Studio, when I try to run all my Unit Tests, it fails almost immediately with following error in Messages (Gradle Build):

```
Error:Gradle: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':Module:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources'.
      > /Users/me/path/to/my/project/src/test/resources/fixtures/activity_feed.json:0:0: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Seems like yet another variant of **Content is not allowed in prolog** error, which doesn't often makes sense, as I found out searching for a solution. In my case, it points to a JSON file, which obviously doesn't contain any prolog code.

Comment: For the most part those issues are some weird character at the beginning of the file.  Would the solutions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569123/content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-saxparserexception work for a json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find Build Variants view:

- left tool pane
- View -> Tool Windows -> Build Variants

Once there, locate:

> Test Artifact: **Android Instrumentation Tests**

and instead Android Instrumentation Tests select:

> Test Artifact: **Unit Tests**