# Facing JDOMParseException : Content not allowed in prolog

Tags: spring-mvc

```
org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 1 of document file:/home/omfys/Desktop/eclipse: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:501)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:847)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:826)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Content is not allowed in Prolog SAXParserException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569123/content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-saxparserexception)

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your document is probably incorrect.

View : [Content is not allowed in Prolog SAXParserException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569123/content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-saxparserexception)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a class level attribute for the SAXBuilder ...
like this:

```
public class MyClass {

   private static final SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();

   public static Document myMethod(String argument) throws Exception {
      ... your functionality with the saxBuilder
   }
}
```

(If this is the case) just declare and initialize the SAXBuilder within the method and it will be fixed ...